sentence-transformers: combined parallelization for custom chunking function and encode_multi_process()
I am working in Python 3.10, using a sentence-transformers model to encode/embed a list of text strings. I want to use sentence-transformer's encode_multi_process method to exploit my GPU. This is a very specific function that takes in a string, or a list of strings, and produces a numeric vector (or list of vectors). The function distributes the work among system CPUs and GPUs.
I also want to parallelize my custom chunking function create_chunks, which splits a raw text string into chunks that are small enough to fit into the model's constraints. So, for any given text input, it has to go through create_chunks before going through encode_multi_process. I'm pretty sure that using multiple CPU cores to parallelize this step is the way to go.
Right now I am considering using multiprocessing to apply create_chunks to my dataset, and then encode_multi_process, but this seems inefficient: the chunks that come out of create_chunks have to wait until the whole dataset is finished before moving on to encode_multi_process. Are there more efficient Python alternatives? I have to build my solution around encode_multi_process, which is the main difficulty.
I wish I could use Dask, but the language model is too big to fit into a Dask task graph.


Are there more efficient alternatives?

Yes.
If we speak about efficiency-of-work completion in time, use more resources and more performant resources to shorten the time-to-complete the work. A 1.5 GHz clocked herd of SIMD-SM engines, no matter how many are present on the GPU fabric, will perform the same amount of a pure-[SERIAL] work no better than 3 times slower, than a 4.5 GHz clocked CPU ( if using a single CPU-core only ).
If we speak about efficiency-of-resources' use, use better organisation-of-work, not to let a single resource instance ( RAM, CPU, GPU, storage ) unused on CP/M critical-chain-of-process-flow. Then the end-to-end processing time could not get, given the resources pools, shorter, unless processing strategy gets refactored into a faster organisation-of-work. On the contrary, any resource, not used during the work performed on the CP/M critical-chain-of-process-flow, reduces the efficiency-of-resources' use. This reads into avoiding any mutual-coordination ( GPU-kernel-code "barriers" for synchronisations are example of such, .await()-s, any kind of locking, Python GIL-lock included, shared-queues and any similar high-level code constructors are examples, that in effect block the flow of work on CP/M, thus decrease both the efficiency-of-work and efficiency-of-resources' use )
Latency ( a time your next processing step, be it on CP/M critical-chain-of-process-flow or not, has to wait for "products" from the slowest of the preceding processing steps ) can in well organised flow-of-work get masked ( called latency-masking ).
Example might be, if your input data is big enough to payback the add-on costs of instantiations of any process-based concurrent work ( details matter, a lot as costs are additive and sequential to the intent-of-work ), split your input text processing into 2 parts, if you have 2 GPU engines, each one processed by one of such process-flow, the first starting from beginning sentence[0:half], the other one starting ( at the same time ) processing the 2nd half sentence[half:].
Similar scheme applies for any number of resources you can populate the work to harness them ( increasing both the efficiency-of-resources' usage and the efficiency-of-work completion in time ), for which the add-on costs of using additional "on-demand-mobilised" resources does not diminish or devastate benefits they ought bring  ( becoming more expensive in add-on costs, then the effect they help bring for the process-flow efficiency-of-work completion in time -- "negative" speedup ( technically speaking S < 1.0, not negative ) ).
The last, but not least available strategy is the "shift-in-paradigm", if you can invent a straight different technology, that can do the same, with perhaps other types of resources and processing-steps, but in shorter time.

Thanks a lot for your detailed conceptual overview. This is helping me come up with a few ideas.
